# Android Interstitial video ads

Tags: android, video, admob, interstitial

I just finished my app, a tool that you use for about 5min and then export, so I have considered to show a video ad before each exportation. The debate begins here, which ad company is better? I like Admob because I have other apps with banners and it's very confortable to have all I need in one web.
But I read that Admob is not the better one and I've heard too that with interstitial video ads you get the same revenues that with interstitial image ads, it's that true?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't choose now.

Pick 3 contenders. Deploy you app with the SDK for all 3, and use mediation (such as Admob's) in order to flick between them. Then you can try all 3 by switching between them using the mediation web console without needing to redeploy.

I suspect you will want more than one anyway as they don't always have ads available in all regions at all times, so you are going to want to use mediation anyhow.

And don't ask which 3 - that is not a question for this site.